# Asp.net MVC2 in VB.NET on Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, mono

I'm having problems running MVC2. I've compiled defult MVC project and deployed it on working mono setup (MVC1 works without problems, but only as C#, VB.net MVC1 fails with a message similar to this one). When I try to access MVC2 web (VB.NET version, C# works) I get this message:

```
Compiler Error Message: 
VBNC30456: 'RenderPartial' is not a member of 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
    ~/Views/Shared/Site.Master
```

I've set System.Web.MVC to Copy local, but to no avail.

```
# mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.4 (tarball Tue May 25 19:27:01 CEST 2010)
```

Comment: What version of mono do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono's VB compiler does not support 2008 features, like extension methods.

The way to get around this is to use Visual Studio to precompile your application and copy it to wherever you intend to use Mono to serve it.  This way, Mono's VB compiler should never be invoked.